# Updating dynamic Tkinter label with iterated list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently building a Python app which allows you to keep track of outgoing payments. I have opted to use a Tkinter UI because it will be used by someone who doesn't have a vast knowledge of programming.

I create a class called `Main` after following a tutorial on **zetcode**:

```
class Main(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="#554433")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.outgoingsString = StringVar()
        self.addOnString = gatherList()

        self.outgoingsList = Label(self, textvariable=self.outgoingsString, font = ["Verdana", 20], foreground = "#1F3424").pack()
        self.outgoingsString.set(self.addOnString)

        quitButton = Button(self, text="Add", command=addListItem)
        quitButton.place(x=20, y=360)
```

`gatherlist()` is a function I wrote which iterates over a list of lists to generate what will be seen on startup:

```
def gatherList():
    newString = ""
    for x in range(0, len(listOfOutgoingPayments)):
        newString += ("Name: " + listOfOutgoingPayments[x][0] + " | Money: " + str(listOfOutgoingPayments[x][1]) + "\n")
        int(listOfOutgoingPayments[x][1])

    print(newString)
    return newString
```

`listOfOutgoingPayments` is a list which contains, by default, the following:
`[["TV", 20]]`

This is what happens upon startup.

[image: This is what happens upon startup.]

This is what I want, it looks nice (for a very basic build) and displays what I want. However, pressing "`Add`" brings up another GUI, which is a class called `ListItem`:

```
class ListItem(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="#334455")
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Simple")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.nameEntry = Entry(self)
        self.nameEntry.pack()

        self.submitNameEntry = Button(self, text="Submit Name", command=self.getTextName)
        self.submitNameEntry.pack()

        self.moneyEntry = Entry(self)
        self.moneyEntry.pack()

        self.submitMoneyEntry = Button(self, text="Submit Money", command=self.getTextMoney)
        self.submitMoneyEntry.pack()

        self.submitButton = Button(self, text="Finish and Submit", command=self.finish)
        self.submitButton.pack()

    def getTextName(self):
        self.nameOfListItem = self.nameEntry.get()
        print(self.nameOfListItem)

    def getTextMoney(self):
        self.amountOfMoney = self.moneyEntry.get()
        print(self.amountOfMoney)

    def finish(self):
        listOfOutgoingPayments.append([self.nameOfListItem, self.amountOfMoney])
        gatherList()
        self._close()

    def _close(self):
        self.master.destroy()
```

However, when the window closes (after inputting some information like this)

[image: The next window that appears upon clicking <code>Add</code>]

the text on the original box doesn't update at all. I made the program print the contents of `listOfOutgoingPayments` and **it has updated, with all of the right information which has just been inputted.**

I thought that the window needed updating, so in `finish(self)` in the `ListItem` class I added `root.initUI()`, but I get an `AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'initUI'`.

Can anyone shed some light on the problem and possibly help solve it?
Any help appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

The function `addListItem` is as follows:

```
def addListItem():
    itemAdd = Tk()
    itemAdd.geometry("150x150")
    addItem = ListItem(itemAdd)
    itemAdd.mainloop()
```

Comment: What function is `addListItem` ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Ah, sorry, didn't put that. It's this: def addListItem():
 itemAdd = Tk()
 itemAdd.geometry("150x150")
 addItem = ListItem(itemAdd)
 itemAdd.mainloop()

It's the function that makes the smaller box shown nearer the end of the question.

Comment: You should update in the question.

Comment: `listOfOutgoingPayments`  is a global variable? What you want is update `outgoingsString` in your function `gatherString`. `outgoingsString `  is an instance variable. I suggest giving a reference to `Main` to `ListItem`...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create more than one instance of `Tk`. Your program should always have exactly one instance, and you should call `mainloop()` exactly once. If you need more windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about `TopLevel`. I'll definitely look into that when I get back to my computer.